# I want get record after 4 days of last_update?

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have tried but not getting a expected result.
Following is MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_order_final
WHERE od_last_update >$current_date'
AND DATEDIFF( DATE( od_last_update ) , $current_date ) = 4
```

Comment: you have a extra comma, and what is `$current_date` ? there is no such thing in MySQL ...

Comment: What is the datatype of `od_last_update` column? Also clarify do you need all records on 4th day only or after 4 days of the last update?

Comment: @Mihai its current date i have write this query in php..

Comment: @peterm its datetime column and current date is also in same format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works properly and gives expected result Just tested it [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/026d0/1) but with `CURDATE()`:

```
select *
FROM tbl_order_final
WHERE od_last_update >CURDATE()
AND DATEDIFF( od_last_update , CURDATE() ) = 4
```

**Note:** perhaps you have not any data with dates greater than current date so `WHERE od_last_update >$current_date'` is cause of returning no result in this case.

Comment: As per my understanding in the function DATEDIFF, latest date is the first parameter while the older date is another. So here od_last_update is older date so it will give you `-4` rather than 4.

Comment: NO, it will give `4` because `od_last_update >CURDATE()`, look at the first condition of where clauses.

Comment: @FarhangAmary, I accepted my fault. I didn't see the first where clause.